# I lost salt mass after evaporation

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I was doing an evaporation experiment and I used salt and water. I started off with 5 g of salt and after the evaporation process, I was only left with 4.3 g of salt. Why is this?

Comment: Did you try heating the salt without dissolving it first? The salt could have started off with some moisture content.